# In Pandas, how to apply a customized function using Group mean on Groupby Object

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my input data.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(10,3), columns= list("ABC") )

      A         B         C
0  0.557303  1.657976 -0.091638
1 -0.769201  1.305553 -0.248403
2  1.251513 -0.634947  0.100130
3 -1.030045 -0.268972  1.328666
4  0.665483 -0.133410  0.151235
5  0.703294 -0.525490  0.109413
6  0.549441  0.002626 -0.005841
7  0.454866  1.094490 -1.946760
8 -0.152995 -0.736689 -0.367252
9 -0.632906  1.066869  0.303271
```

I want to create groups based on value of column A. So I slice A first. And define a function. Then I use apply method on the Groupby Obj. I am expecting the new column to be the difference between B and C over the group mean of A.

```
b=np.linspace(-1, 1,5)

def tmpF(x):
  x['newCol']= (x['B']-x['C'])/df1['A'].mean()
return x

df1.groupby(np.digitize(df1['A'],b)).apply(tmpF)
```

However, I am only using the mean value of the entire column A. I know df1['A'].mean() is wrong but I dont know how to access the group mean instead.
How to solve that ?

Comment: I tried it. It failed with the error "ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)."

Comment: Thanks. It works !!! It failed just because a stupid typo on my end. I used np.digitize(df1,b) instead of df1['A']. It causes the dimension issue.

Comment: Yes, you solved it. The answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `df1['A']` to `x['A']` in function `tmpF`:

```
b=np.linspace(-1, 1,5)

def tmpF(x):
  x['newCol']= (x['B']-x['C'])/x['A'].mean()
return x

df1.groupby(np.digitize(df1['A'],b)).apply(tmpF)
```